# /_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail email is sent, but it does not arrive

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, jquery, email, ajax

I've been trying to send an email over REST using /_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmai, but seems like the emails just never arrive.

**Current setup**

- SharePoint Online
- I send emails to myself and to other **internal** mailboxes within office 365 tenant
- When I type a nonexistent email the script fails with an error. And if I use the correct one it is sent successfully, but it just never arrives
- I tried several ways to send emails with and without AdditionalHeaders, but nothing seems to work

Can someone help me, please, to figure out what I could be doing wrong?

### This is the code I've been using:

```
var subject = "SUBJECT OF THE MAIL";
var mailContent = "Some Heading for the mail Content Content";
var toList = ["correctUser@domain.com"]

//Send email message over REST
function sendMail(toList, subject, mailContent) {
    var restUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +     "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail",
restHeaders = {
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
    "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
},
mailObject = {
    'properties': {
        '__metadata': {
            'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties'
        },
        'To': {
            'results': toList
        },
        'Subject': subject,
        'Body': mailContent,
        "AdditionalHeaders":
            {
                "__metadata":
                   { "type": "Collection(SP.KeyValue)" },
                "results":
                [
                    {
                        "__metadata": {
                            "type": 'SP.KeyValue'
                        },
                        "Key": "content-type",
                        "Value": 'text/html',
                        "ValueType": "Edm.String"
                    }
                ]
            }

    }
};
return $.ajax({
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: restUrl,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(mailObject),
    headers: restHeaders
});

} 

$(function(){
    sendMail(toList, subject, mailContent).then(function(data)    {console.log(data.d)})
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, the account I was using when sending these messages did not have Exchange Online license assigned. So, essentially, I need to have a mailbox to send emails via **SendEmail** service.